# adGallery how to keep slideshow moving when image is clicked on

Tags: jquery

I am using adGallery on a site from :

http://adgallery.codeplex.com/documentation

but when you click on a image then the slideshow stops moving, i cant seem tow work out how to pause on that slide and then carry on?

```
$(function () {

    var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery(
        { slideshow: {
            enable: true,
            autostart: true,
            speed: 300,
            stop_on_scroll: false, 
        }
        }

    );
    galleries[0].settings.effect = 'fade';
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD Gallery seems quite configurable using callback functions. You can use `afterImageVisible` callback to restart the slideshow:

```
var galleries = $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
    callbacks: {
        afterImageVisible: function() {
            this.slideshow.start();
        }
    }
});​
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wldaunfr/mB9qV/